# Change default python from 3.7 to 3.6 or 3.5 on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: python

To use Carla simulator,
I need to use python 3.6 or 3.5 version of python.
However my current version for python is 3.7
How can I temporaraily use python 3.6/3.5 ?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise using [Conda](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/).  It allows you to create a virtual python environment in whatever version you want.